# SwiftUI Buttons not fire action in ScrollView (untappable) on iPhone Xs, works on iPhone 7 and simulators

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a list of button inside a ScrollView like this:

```
 ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack(spacing: 8) {
                ForEach(Product.allCases, id: \.self) { p in
                    Button(action: {
                       print("product selected")
                    }) {
                        Text(p.description)
                    }
                    .frame(minWidth: 60,minHeight: 40,  alignment: .center)
                    .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.3),
                            radius: 3, x: 3, y: 3)
                }
            }
        }
```

Buttons are untappable/not working on iPhone Xs, working fine on iPhone7 and simulator, what wrong? (Note: I've also tried `onTapGesture` instead of `action` and it is the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a bug when putting `Buttons` inside `ScrollView` in SwiftUI for some devices. My current work around is to use `UIScrollView` wrapper instead.

```
struct UIScrollViewWrapper<Content: View>: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    var content: () -> Content

    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIScrollViewViewController {
        let vc = UIScrollViewViewController()
        vc.hostingController.rootView = AnyView(self.content())
        return vc
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ viewController: UIScrollViewViewController, context: Context) {
        viewController.hostingController.rootView = AnyView(self.content())
    }
}

class UIScrollViewViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let v = UIScrollView()
        v.isPagingEnabled = true
        v.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        return v
    }()

    var hostingController: UIHostingController<AnyView> = UIHostingController(rootView: AnyView(EmptyView()))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.addSubview(self.scrollView)
        self.pinEdges(of: self.scrollView, to: self.view)

        self.hostingController.willMove(toParent: self)
        self.hostingController.view.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.scrollView.addSubview(self.hostingController.view)
        self.pinEdges(of: self.hostingController.view, to: self.scrollView)
        self.hostingController.didMove(toParent: self)

    }

    func pinEdges(of viewA: UIView, to viewB: UIView) {
        viewA.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        viewB.addConstraints([
            viewA.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewB.leadingAnchor),
            viewA.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewB.trailingAnchor),
            viewA.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewB.topAnchor),
            viewA.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewB.bottomAnchor),
        ])
    }

}
```

Credit of this code from [timothycosta](https://gist.github.com/timothycosta/0d8f64afeca0b6cc29665d87de0d94d2)

Then setting the ScrollView height in SwiftUI using `frame`

```
  UIScrollViewWrapper() {
          
        }.frame(maxHeight: 60)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you manage to solve the problem eventually.

But I did solve it by adding the `.background` modifier.
For some reason, the buttons are untappable without background.

Hope this helps anyone who experiencing this problem.